# Repeat last normal command

Tags: normal-mode, repeated-commands

Well, there is `;` to repeat the last move in some cases. 
There is the `.` to repeat last change. 
But if I just did `za` or `@a`, is there a way to repeat it? I guess such a mechanism should ignore plain movements.

for example, I have a mapping such that H does `o<ESC>D`, or new line.
If I do `.` , it only repeats the `D`. So, to do so just for defined mappings would be a start.

I am almost certain that there is no way out of the box.

Comment: Please dont substantially change the question once an answer is posted. you can always ask a new one.

Comment: I didn't. I just added an example. I didn't intend one to provide a solution only for these cases of @reg, za. The question is to repeat any normal command. Will check repeat. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`.` repeats the last change, and usually does what you want (combine with, *e.g.*, `cgn` for a great sequence). For registers, `@@` repeats the last register. `@:` repeats the last ex command. This is particularly handy with `:normal!` or `:global`.

For mappings, I use [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat). You (and plugin authors) can have mappings take advantage of it so that `.` works as expected.

As you've noticed, the `ft` family of motions can be repeated with `,;`. The only other 'repeatable' motion I'm aware of is `/?` searches via `nN`.

In general, certain commands don't *have* a repeatable version. For example, it doesn't make sense to have a builtin to repeat `za`, because (a) it's two characters ; (b) it doesn't edit text ; (c) it's easily mappable.